# Помогите определить части речи

Tags: морфология, части-речи, наречия, местоимения

Это последнее, обещаю...просто опять все как-то двояко...

> 1) Прежде чем они добрались до города, им навстречу УЖЕ бежали люди...

Уже -частица?

> 2) Хотя дождь шел всю ночь, в лесу было УЖЕ сухо.

Наречие или частица?Думаю наречие...

> 3) ОТТОГО, быть может, ЧТО в глазах мелькали деревья...., САМЫЕ
>   разнообразные мысли приходили ей в голову.

ОТТОГО и ЧТО - это разделенный вводным словом слюз - ОТТОГО ЧТО или наречие ОТТОГО и союз ЧТО?

САМЫЕ - прилагательное?

> 4)У заборов были деревья, бросавшие теперь при солнце широкую тень,
>   ТАК ЧТО заборы и ворота на ОДНОЙ стороне совершенно утопали в
>   потемках...

Так что - ?

Одной - местоимение?

Comment: Lisa, не надо ничего обещать. Вас никто не ограничивает, задавайте столько вопросов, сколько пожелаете. И не вспоминайте всуе предыдущие, через некоторое время они окажутся далеко друг от друга при любой сортировке - и связать один с другим будет невозможно.

Comment: Да я вас просто уже достала этими союзами,частицами, местоимениями...но сама разобраться не могу....видите как по-разному пользователи смотрят на предмет...вот и я сначала думаю по-одному, потом начинаю сомневаться,задумываться, и не могу решить.

Comment: Я вас умоляю... Не обращайте внимание, каждый вопрос - польза ресурсу, лишь бы по теме был и понятен желающему ответить.  А кто как смотрит - не имеет значения. Для них есть кнопки (типа лайк-дислайк). Они, кстати, и у вас скоро появятся, когда и если репутация подрастет.

Answer (score 1):

> 1)  Прежде чем они добрались до города, им навстречу УЖЕ бежали
>   люди...

По-моему, здесь УЖЕ по своему значению стоит ближе к наречию с временным значением, чем к частице.

> 2)  Хотя дождь шел всю ночь, в лесу было УЖЕ сухо.

То же и здесь: наречие. Ср.:  *Хотя дождь шел всю ночь, в лесу СЕЙЧАС было сухо.*

> 3)  ОТТОГО, быть может, ЧТО в глазах мелькали деревья..., САМЫЕ
>   разнообразные мысли приходили ей в голову.

ОТТОГО находится в главной части СПП, является соотносительным словом -- местоименным наречием.

> 3)  …САМЫЕ разнообразные…

Здесь САМЫЕ -- частица, имеющая усилительное значение.

> 4) У заборов были деревья, бросавшие теперь при солнце широкую тень,
>   ТАК ЧТО заборы и ворота… утопали в потемках...

ТАК ЧТО = поэтому, вследствие чего. Союз. См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/252585

> 4)  …заборы и ворота на ОДНОЙ стороне совершенно утопали в потемках...

Прилагательное.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В ответе **Vera** прозвучало, что *"Здесь САМЫЕ -- местоименное прилагательное… **У частицы значение соответствия действительности (на самом деле)"**.*

Опровергать возможность называния слова "самый" в сочетании с прилагательными местоименным прилагательным я не буду. ГОСТов на термины нет, лингвистов у нас много, каждый вправе пользоваться своей терминологией.

Приведу только несколько слов из книги Бабайцевой В.В. "Явления переходности в грамматике русского языка":

> В учебниках и учебных пособиях слово ***самый*** обычно включается в
>   разряд определительных местоимений, хотя во многих работах показано,
>   что в современном русском языке нет местоимения ***самый***.
>
> Наиболее очевидна квалификация слова ***самый*** как
>   формообразовательной **частицы** в сочетании с прилагательными для
>   выражения значения превосходной степени: *Да приснятся тебе самые
>   лучшие, самые красивые сны* (А. Чехов); *Калиныч был человек самого
>   кроткого, самого весёлого нрава* (И. Тургенев); *Всем известно, что
>   сорока -- самая болтливая птица* (К. Паустовский)...

Comment: По поводу ТАК ЧТО я думала, что может быть и так:  деревья бросали тень ТАК(таким образом), ЧТО заборы....  но запятой нет, значит это союз ТАК ЧТО.....спасибо.

Comment: Самая середина лета,  в эту самую минуту, до самой смерти - местоимение указывает  пределы, указывает на точность определения места, времени, разные у него функции.

Comment: @Vera, Вы приводите примеры сочетания "самый" с **существительными**. в вопросе же у **Lisa** -- **прилагательное**. По-моему, _"две большие разницы"_.

Comment: Полистала учебники.  Если "самый большой в мире", то это сложная форма превосходной степени, но "самый" в этом случае скромно называют  просто словом (не местоимением  и не частицей). Вряд ли вообще прилагательное "разнообразный" (=неоднородный)  имеет превосходную степень. Слово "самый" все дружно относят к определительным местоимениям, частицей никто не называет. Оно может относиться к прилагательному или существительному, но при этом всегда  указывает на точность и полноту проявления предмета/признака (ну самый-самый).

Comment: Полностью согласна со Славой. Самый- формообразующая частица для образования превосходной степени качественного прилагательного. Нет сомнения, что разнообразный-качественное прилагательное. Возможно сказать более разнообразный, менее разнообразный, очень разнообразный. В любом случае частица усиливает значение прилагательного. Слава прав .

Comment: Slava, если вам не трудно, приведите, пожалуйста, цитату из учебника, в котором слово "самый" названо формообразующей частицей. Может быть, и я с вами полностью соглашусь и приду к выводу, что "нет сомнения". У Розенталя же и в вузовской современной грамматике я пока что  не нашла "таких сведений".

Answer (score 0):

Поправки к ответу Slava

3) …САМЫЕ разнообразные…
Здесь САМЫЕ -- местоименное прилагательное, указывает на предел признака. Также Употр. для образования превосходной степени. С. сильный. С. быстрый. С. короткий.  У частицы значение соответствия действительности (на самом деле).

4) …заборы и ворота на ОДНОЙ стороне совершенно утопали в потемках...
Местоимение: 
Один красив, другой умен – какой-нибудь в ряду сходных предметов.

Comment: Да, я согласна с 4-м, ОДОЙ здесь действительно подразумевает "один из ряда предметов"... но меня смущает, что он только подразумевает это, нет самой цепи слов "на одной стороне утопали в потемках, а на другой нет".Это ни на что не влияет?

По поводу САМЫЕ я все еще сомневаюсь...вот почему-то САМЫЕ для меня - как будто не превосходная степень, а что-то в роде- "КАКИЕ ТОЛЬКО мысли НЕ приходили"...

Comment: _Да, я согласна с 4-м, ОДНОЙ здесь действительно подразумевает "один из ряда предметов"... но меня смущает, что он только подразумевает это, нет самой цепи слов "на одной стороне утопали в потемках, а на другой нет"._     Да если бы даже и было противопоставление, что с того?  См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/160988 :  **друго́й**  
**III прил. **  
**2.**
Противоположный _(о стороне, крае и т.п. чего-либо).
отт._   Употребляется при противопоставлении.

Comment: Это не местоимение, это прилагательное, Слава прав. Прилагательное в значении "единый, целостный, нераздельный". Имеется в виду, что заборы и ворота находятся в одном месте, а не в разных. Это не "один из ряда предметов", речь не об одном из заборов, а о целостности плоскости, стороны,на которой и заборы, и ворота.

Comment: "Переулок был весь в садах, и у заборов росли липы, бросавшие теперь при луне широкую тень, так что заборы и ворота на одной стороне совершенно утопали в потемках.".. Итак, переулок с двумя, конечно, сторонами, одна из которых постоянно в тени, в отличие от другой. Обратим внимание, что сравниваются две стороны - одна и другая, это и есть значение местоимения. Вряд ли Чехов имел в виду "слившиеся в единую плоскость заборы". Для примера: Постепенно  диалекты слились в один язык (единый, целостный).